# How to Increment a UILabel?

Tags: iphone, uilabel, nstimer

I have a UILabel with a value of 0, and an int with a value of 300. How do I use NSTimer to have the UILabel go from 0 to 300 in 2 seconds? I want it to look like it's being added up incrementally.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a different solution:

I knew I wanted the "count up" to last 3 seconds... which is 60*0.05... basically the timer is hitting the method 60 times to get to the total amount.

```
addUpAb = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(addUpTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)addUpTimer {
    int addNo = abTOT / 60;    
    abInt += addNo;

    abductionCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", abInt];

    if(abInt >= abTOT) {
        [addUpAb invalidate];
        abCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", abTOT];
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should use CADisplayLink instead of NSTimers to do the animation.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo... it works fine for me (performance-wise).. what are your reasons for recommending CADisplayLink?

Comment: It would sync the animation with the display, resulting in a smoother animation. In your case, if something happens (eg.: a phone call, something on background) the NSTimer would fire not exactly 0.05s later. (And I just noticed Alexey said the same thing, heh)

Comment: Awesome... I'll play with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually `NSTimer` precision is about 50-100 milliseconds so it can't be so smooth as you want. But you can schedule timer for 0.05 and measure how much time had really passed from the beginning. After use

```
value = timePassedInSeconds*300/2; 
NSString* label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", value];
```

if this won't be smooth enough try to use display link instead of `NSTimer`.

Comment: Thanks Alexey... how do i measure how much time had passed?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? Are you trying to show some sort of point/score animation? You can do what you want if you do the math and fire off the timer at the interval you want, but I doubt you'll get what you want. You might want to look at UIImageView and feed it an array of images to animate or do the animations yourself with by painting.

Comment: I'm actually displaying a total count of something... but wanted to fancy it up with a "count up".